# Как из 2-х строк с разным значением Ивента собрать одну строку?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите как можно собрать из 2 строк одну. Сам пока с SQL научился очень простые запросы составлять

Имеется следующий запрос

```
select 
    event_.*
from (select 
    dialog_id,
    agent_id,
    "event",
    created_on_tz
from chat_dialog_event 
where 
    agent_id = 1 and 
    ("event" = 'START' or "event" = 'RESPONSE') 
    and (created_on_tz between '2019-02-01'::date and '2019-02-01'::date + interval '1 day')) event_
```

и соответственно к нему скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как из такой таблицы можно получить таблицу следующего вида:

**dialog_id** - идентификатор диалога
**start_on_tz** - время когда произошло событие **START** (максимальное, т.е. время последнего события **START** в текущем **dialog_id**)
**response_on_tz** - время когда произошло событие **RESPONSE**
**agent_id** - идентификатор агента,
**difference** - разница времени в секундах между **response_on_tz** и **start_on_tz**

Comment: `group by dialog_id, start_on_tz` и получаем максимумы/минимумы вроде `max(case when event='START' then created_on_tz end)` ну и во внешнем запросе где уже все времена будут вычесть одно из другого

Comment: @Mike, хорошая идея. Я как раз уже собрал 2 даты, только я там намудрил через вложенные подзапросы к оригинальной таблице... В общем нагородил, но результаты вроде совпадают

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему следующим образом:

```
select 
        dialog_.*,
        round(extract(epoch from dialog_.response_on_tz - dialog_.start_on_tz)::numeric, 0) seconds
    from (select 
            event_.dialog_id,
            event_.agent_id,
            max(case when "event" = 'START' then created_on_tz end) start_on_tz,
            max(case when "event" = 'RESPONSE' then created_on_tz end) response_on_tz
        from (select 
            dialog_id,
            agent_id,
            "event",
            created_on_tz
        from chat_dialog_event 
        where 
            agent_id = 2 and 
            ("event" = 'START' or "event" = 'RESPONSE') 
            and (created_on_tz between '2019-02-12'::date and '2019-02-12'::date + interval '1 day')) event_
        group by dialog_id, agent_id
        order by dialog_id) dialog_
    where dialog_.start_on_tz is not null and dialog_.response_on_tz is not null
```